# How to make query based on logged in user

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to *JasperReports Server*.

I am having different campaigns in my DB. And users assigned to these campaigns.

I want my *JR Server* user to provide campaign IDs to run a report.
For this, I have create a query and an input control to show the list of campaigns in a list to take input from user.

The query I created shows all the campaigns in the DB.

I want to show only those campaigns in which the logged in user is assigned.

Is there any way to do this in *JasperReports Server*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
SELECT campaign_name
FROM some_table
INNER JOIN some_other_table sot ON ( ... )
WHERE sot.username = $P{LoggedInUsername}
```

In the documentation you'll find more comprehensive explanations and lists of available parameters.